# Safe copy file in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

The following code, was ripped out from a C# code. I wonder what is the importance of For.... To ...statement within the code?

```
Public Sub CopyFile(sourceFile  As String, backupFile  As String, overwrite As Boolean)
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceFile) Then
    Throw New ArgumentNullException("sourceFile")
End If
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(backupFile) Then
    Throw New ArgumentNullException("backupFile")
End If
' According to MSDN Certain file attributes, Hidden and ReadOnly, can be combined. Other attributes, such as Normal, must be used alone. 
If File.Exists(backupFile) Then
    File.SetAttributes(backupFile, FileAttributes.Normal)
End If
            ' ????????
For index As Integer = 0 To 9
    Try
        File.Copy(sourceFile, backupFile, overwrite)
        Exit Try
    Catch ex  As FileNotFoundException
        Throw
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not overwrite Then
            Throw
        End If
        If index = 9 Then
            Throw
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
    End Try
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like it's setting up a retry loop - try 10 times and if it doesn't work and it's not another error (file not found, or an exception where `overwrite` is false), throw an exception.  Probably trying to work around accessing a file that is locked by another process.

Comment: On a side note, you could make use of VB.Net's conditional exception handling to simplify this code a little bit (...`Catch ex As Exception When overwrite AndAlso index < 9`...).